# Sub-setting / Matching row and columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, match, subset

Ok, so I need a very specific formula for subsetting. From matrix x, I only want to keep elements defined by *rows* and *columns*. The undesired elements should then be replaced by zeros. Example below:

```
> x <- matrix(c(65,46,52,76,34,345,65,87,12,53),nrow = 5,ncol = 2)
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   65  345
[2,]   46   65
[3,]   52   87
[4,]   76   12
[5,]   34   53

> rows <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5)
> cols <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
```

*magic*

```
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   65  345
[2,]    0   65
[3,]   52   87
[4,]   76    0
[5,]    0   53
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of magic is called matrix indexing. If you had `rows` and `cols` be the ones you didn't want, or if matrix indexing allowed for negative values, it would be even easier.

```
y <- matrix(0, nrow=5, ncol=2)
y[cbind(rows,cols)] <- x[cbind(rows,cols)]
y
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   65  345
## [2,]    0   65
## [3,]   52   87
## [4,]   76    0
## [5,]    0   53
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing "by hand," and have the capability of using negative subscripting, by knowing that a matrix can be treated as a vector with indexing going down the columns.

```
k <- (cols-1)*nrow(x) + rows
x[-k] <- 0
x
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   65  345
## [2,]    0   65
## [3,]   52   87
## [4,]   76    0
## [5,]    0   53
```

Comment: Both of these are very nice. Especially the second one.

Comment: Thanks. Matrix indexing is my favorite underused feature of R. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, not necessarily pretty or efficient. Loop through every cell, if it's not in your original set of coordinates then set it to 0.

```
x <- matrix(c(65,46,52,76,34,345,65,87,12,53),nrow = 5,ncol = 2)
rows <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5)
cols <- c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
coords <- paste(rows,cols)
numRows <- 5
numCols <- 2
for (i in 1:numRows){
  for (j in 1:numCols){
    if (!(paste(i,j) %in% coords)){
      x[i,j] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kind of baroque:

```
    indicies <- NULL
    for (iter in 1:length(rows)) {
      indicies <- rbind(indicies, c(rows[iter], cols[iter]))
    }

    indicies
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    3    1
[5,]    3    2
[6,]    4    1
[7,]    5    2

    y <- matrix(rep(0, 10), nrow=5, ncol=2)
    for (k in 1:nrow(indicies)) {
      y[indicies[k,1], indicies[k,2]] <- x[indicies[k,1], indicies[k,2]]
    }
    y
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]   65  345
    [2,]    0   65
    [3,]   52   87
    [4,]   76    0
    [5,]    0   53
```